# Oven Terminal block melted

Tags: electrical, wiring, repair

Wondering if I could hardwire just the negative wire of oven plug directly to the negative wire of the oven. The positive and neutral are connected to the terminal block. The negative connection of the terminal block has been burnt off and is no longer part of the ovens terminal. Would it be safe to leave the positive and neutral wired through the terminal block and hardwire the negatives together? Using electrical tape to make sure none of the negative wiring is exposed.

Comment: The oven terminal block became over heated and burned and melted for some reason. That problem needs to be well understood well before you go to figuring out how to re-wire things.

Comment: Was the terminal block the correct size?

Comment: A couple of things:  the terms "positive" and "negative" are for DC circuits not AC. The wires are generally referred to as "hot" "neutral" and "ground".   2nd:  Like JW & Michael said, you need to determine the cause of the melting.  It might just have been a loose connection on the prong on the plug where it connects to the outlet, or a real and serious problem with the oven. Don't monkey this around, replace the outlet and possibly the pig tail, then get a meter with an amp clamp and determine loads. You may need to get help with this from a friend with more knowledge.

Comment: Agree with George's recommendation to get some more knowledgeable help here. Your use of terms like 'positive' and 'negative' here is completely out of place and indicates to me a lack of knowledge which could be dangerous - particularly around a high power appliance like an oven. Please call a friend on this one.

Comment: @brhans *hence the presence here*.  I don't totally object to the use of positive and negative, because it's right half the time :)

Comment: Is there a separate wired ground?  Because if not, and the neutral takes a similar hit... it WILL electrify the chassis of the range.  This is why 3-wire ungrounded range connections are bad.

Comment: Where, precisely, is this "terminal block" you're referring to?

Answer (score 12):

The most common cause of melting/burned terminals is a failure in the heating element.  These often fail in a way that allows the heating element, which is encased inside a metallic tube with an insulating layer, to make electrical contact with the tube.

In most cases when this happens, it causes excess current to be drawn from the panel and the circuit breaker trips.  But in other cases it fails in such a way that more current than the terminal can handle is drawn but not enough to trip the breaker.

If you remove the heating element and check it with a meter, you should find a relatively low resistance between the two terminals and an infinite resistance from either terminal to the outer shell of the element.  If there is a resistance value read from either terminal to the shell, you have a defective element and it should be replaced.

Your best bet is to replace the burned/damaged part as well.  Makeshift connections here can be dangerous considering this is a relatively high current and also high temperature application and using parts not designed for this application can cause them to fail unexpectedly.